# Was heißt »bleibt über« im Satz »Wer Dateien mit DRM gekauft hat, bleibt über.«?

Tags: meaning

In einem [Artikel auf heise.de](http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/MP3-Player-Microsoft-macht-dem-Zune-den-Garaus-2921846.html) heißt es:

> Am Sonntag hat Microsoft die Bespielung der Zune-Geräte eingestellt. Wer Dateien mit DRM gekauft hat, bleibt über.

Ich denke damit ist gemeint, dass die DRM-Musikdateien voraussichtlich nicht mehr abgespielt werden können. Aber ich kann mir den Ausdruck »bleibt über« nicht erklären. Der Käufer (von DRM-Dateien) *bleibt über*?

Ich kenne das im Kontext von Mengen/Summen, wo z. B. von einem Geldbetrag am Ende des Monats nur 5 Euro über/übrig bleiben. Aber das passt ja hier nicht, oder?

Comment: _Bleibt übrig_ → _bleibt allein zurück_ → _steht allein da_ → _hat ein Problem_. Der Duden gibt als Synonym auch an _zurückbleiben_, und als eine Bedeutung davon _ nicht mitkommen, nicht mitgenommen werden und an seinem Standort, an seinem Platz bleiben_. Stilistisch sicher keine Bestnote …

Comment: Ich vermute eine Fehlübersetzung aus dem Englischen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Als Übersetzung welcher Phrase?

Answer (score 4):

Der Satz scheint mir nicht der beste Stil zu sein, aber gemeint ist wohl, daß die Käufer der DRM-Dateien mit ihrem Problem allein gelassen werden, oder den Zug verpaßt haben, oder die Suppe allein auslöffeln müssen. Da gibt es sicher noch allerlei Äquivalentes.

Answer (score 3):

Im mittelfränkischen Raum, wo ich herkomme, ist *über bleiben* ein Synonym für *übrig bleiben*. Für meinen Geschmack würde das jedoch in den Bereich Dialekt fallen und sollte im redaktionellen Bereich eigentlich nicht verwendet werden.

Comment: Stimme dir voll und ganz zu, wobei das Wort auch in Altbayern vorkommt. Brauchts noch einen Schwaben, der zustimmt, und schon können wir *süddeutsch* dazu sagen ;)

Answer (score 2):

"Bleibt über" wird zumindest in Österreich hin und wieder mit der Bedeutung "steigt schlecht aus" oder "hat ein Problem" verwendet. In so einer Situation könnte man auch "hat den Kürzeren gezogen" oder auf gut Wienerisch "hat den Scherben auf" sagen.